# MySql - get days remaining

Tags: mysql, sql

Users can sign up for a premium listing for a specified number of days, e.g. 30 days.

```
tblPremiumListings

user_id     days     created_date  
---------------------------------
1           30        2013-05-21
2           60        2013-06-21
3           120       2012-06-21
```

How would I select records where there are still days remaining on a premium listing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM tblPremiumListings
WHERE created_date + INTERVAL `days` DAY >= CURDATE()
```

Comment: I'm sure all the answers work fine. This one works and it has the most up votes, so..:-) Many thanks!.

Answer (score 2):

It's easiest to read with INTERVAL

```
select * 
  from tblPremiumListings
 where created_date + interval days day >= now();
```

But I would also change the table to instead of `created_date` and `days` instead store `end_date`. That way the query is

```
select *
  from tblPremiumListings
 where end_date >= now();
```

The benefit of doing like this is that you can put an index on end_date and quickly find all ended premium listings, with your original table you'll always have to do a full table scan to find the records with expired listing.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM 
tblPremiumListings 
WHERE (DATEDIFF(NOW(), created_date) - days)  <= 0
```

See if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the result:

```
SELECT t.user_id
     , t.days
     , t.created_date
  FROM tblPremiumListings t
 WHERE t.created_date + INTERVAL t.days DAY > DATE(NOW())
```

You may want a `>=` comparison operator (instead of `>`) depending on how you define days remaining.

NOTE: the access plan for this query will be full scan of all rows, since MySQL won't be able to do a range scan on an index.  For large sets, having a column that can be indexed to satisfy the query may improve performance, e.g.

```
WHERE t.expire_date > DATE(NOW())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
SELECT * FROM 
tblPremiumListings 
WHERE DATE_ADD(created_date, days)>DATE(NOW())
```